# how to process an XML NODE in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

here is the simple code. i just want to know how to process the node that is being returned by `$reader->expand();`

```
<?php
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open("data.xml"))
{
    die("Failed to open 'data.xml'");
}
while($reader->read())
{
    $node = $reader->expand();
    // just want to know how to process this node now?
}
$reader->close();
?>
```

Comment: By "process" what do you mean? The method just returns a DOM node, so just call its methods or otherwise manipulate the object however you like.

Comment: i want to read the values in this node, i mean if my xml file is 

<articles>
<a1> article 1</a1>
<a2> article 2</a2>
</articles>

now i think the node contains all this info.. right? so how to get this info?

Comment: Have a **thorough read** through the documentation and examples for DOM, at http://php.net/dom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<parent xmlns:dc="myNS"> 
<dc:child> <dc:a>A</dc:a> <dc:b>B</dc:b> </dc:child> 
<dc:child> <dc:a>c</dc:a> <dc:b>d</dc:b> </dc:child> 
<dc:child> <dc:a>e</dc:a> <dc:b>f</dc:b> </dc:child> 
<dc:child> <dc:a>g</dc:a> <dc:b>h</dc:b> </dc:child> 
</parent> 
XML;

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($xml);
while($reader->read()) {
    switch($reader->nodeType) {
        case constant('XMLREADER::ELEMENT'):
            if ($reader->name == 'dc:child') {
                //insert into db
                var_dump($reader->readInnerXml());
            }
            break;
    }
}

$reader->close();
```

Output:

```
string(63) " <dc:a xmlns:dc="myNS">A</dc:a> <dc:b xmlns:dc="myNS">B</dc:b> "
string(63) " <dc:a xmlns:dc="myNS">c</dc:a> <dc:b xmlns:dc="myNS">d</dc:b> "
string(63) " <dc:a xmlns:dc="myNS">e</dc:a> <dc:b xmlns:dc="myNS">f</dc:b> "
string(63) " <dc:a xmlns:dc="myNS">g</dc:a> <dc:b xmlns:dc="myNS">h</dc:b> "
```

Comment: actaully i need to use XMLReader as the file size if very huge, in GBs

Comment: thats very nice of u, let me check this, but please one last thing, help me doing this using DOM..
here is the link for the code, just a single line needed in this code. i will be obliged dear as i m just stuck in this for a long time./
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448542/unable-to-run-the-following-php-xml-reader-code

Comment: actaully i want to put this data into a database, and that will be easy using the DOM coz in ur code the way this data is manipulated i dont knw how to put this in data base each entry respectively.

Comment: If this solution answers your original question, mark it as answered and open up a new question if you are having other problems that are outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: this is the question dear...

here is the simple code. i just want to know how to process the node that is being returned by $reader->expand();

$node = $reader->expand();
    // just want to know how to process this node now?

Comment: $node = $reader->expand(); // just want to know how to process this node now?

the node is returned, now if i m somehow able to handle this using the DOM then its the solution to my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Until you are clearer about what you mean by "process" and why you need to handle those nodes with DOM, I can't help you. Post a real example of what data.xml contains.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent xmlns:dc="myNS">
<dc:child>
<dc:a>A</dc:a>
<dc:b>B</dc:b>
</dc:child>
<dc:child>
<dc:a>c</dc:a>
<dc:b>d</dc:b>
</dc:child>
<dc:child>
<dc:a>e</dc:a>
<dc:b>f</dc:b>
</dc:child>
<dc:child>
<dc:a>g</dc:a>
<dc:b>h</dc:b>
</dc:child>

</parent>

Comment: by process i mean, i want to get the data of each child, and put that in a database.

Comment: more precisely i need a XMLReader + DOM parser by which i can read each node (<dc:child>) from the xml file and save the data (<dc:a>c</dc:a> <dc:b>d</dc:b>) to the database

Comment: and thaks a lot for your time. i would really be very thankful if u please figure this out. anything else u want to know let me know, i can mail u the xml and my php code file if u say...thanks alot

Comment: this is quite right i think. but how to put this into database as the output is
string(63) " A B " string(63) " c d " string(63) " e f " string(63) " g h "

is like this. now how to put each child's values to a separate entry in the data base...?? as i think its output is like a string from every child. i mean to say in database, how can we have a row whose first column have 'A' and 2nd one 'B', and 2nd row has 'C' and 'D' and so on...!

Comment: i am very much grateful to you dear, now this is the last thing that i need to know and i will really be obliged for all this. thanks again...waiting for your reply.

Comment: $reader->readInnerXml() returns a string of all the data in <child> but i want this SEPARATELY. hope u understood what i want to say.

Comment: is there a need to put some case after this or whtever by which i can separately get the values inside each child.

  if ($reader->name == 'dc:child') {